# How to insert a Button with no border, with background image and Text

Tags: c#, wpf, button, border

I would like to create an WPF Button with no border, with background image and insert a center Text. So I have this:

```
         <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TransparentButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

       <Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
          <Button.Content>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="./Resources/Images/bottone_indietro.png" />
                <Label content="Pippo"/>
             </StackPanel>
          </Button.Content>
       </Button>
```

It works but Text "Pippo" is displayed at right of image. It possible to center the text???

Reguards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to centre align text over your image you could put both elements in a `Grid` instead of `StackPanel`

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="./Resources/Images/bottone_indietro.png" />
    <Label Content="Pippo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

`StakcPanel` will stack its children horizontally or vertically whilst `Grid` lets you put one element over other. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Child elements of a Grid are drawn in the order in which they appear in markup or code. As a consequence, layered order (also known as z-order) can be achieved when elements share the same coordinates

You can read more about WPF panels [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HorizontalAlignment` property to centre your text, although it will always be to the right of your `Image`. You also would need to remove the `Orientation` setting on the `StackPanel` so that the text will appear underneath the `Image`... try this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
   <Button.Content>
      <StackPanel>
         <Image Source="./Resources/Images/bottone_indietro.png" />
         <TextBlock Text="Pippo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      </StackPanel>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Note that if you want your text to appear *over the top of* your `Image`, then you shouldn't use a `StackPanel` at all... in that case, you should replace it with a `Grid` instead.